# jQuery AJAX delete only catches the first form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to a php file which deletes a row in the database, now the problem with that is that it only deletes the first row... I've researched this a lot and nothing seems to work so I've decided to come here and ask for help! ( gif to explain it better I'm console.logging the ID selected by jQuery https://thumb.gyazo.com/thumb/1200/_9f12c592fc900ae5fa7b1247257119fd-gif.gif )
here is the code:
**jQuery AJAX**

```
    // Variable to hold request
    var request;

    // Bind to the submit event of our form
    $(".notif_delete").click(function(event){




    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");

    // Serialize the data in the form
       var Data = {

                'notif_id': $('input[name="notif_id"]').val()

            };
    // Fire off the request to php file
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "#notification_control.php",
        type: "post",
        data: Data
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked delete!");
        console.log($('input[name="notif_id"]').val());


    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.log("The following error occurred deleting:" + errorThrown);
                console.log($('input[name=notif_id]').val());
    });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['notif_id'])) {
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM notifications WHERE notif_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['notif_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
<a <?php echo ($isread == 'no') ? 'class="notification unread"' : 'class="notification"'; ?>><?=  '<img src="../profile_pictures/' . $picture . '">' . '<b>'. $from . '</b><br>' . '<span class="notification-text">' . $text . '</span>' . '<span class="notif_delete glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>'?></a>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?=$_SESSION['id']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="notif_id" value="<?=$notif_id?>"> </form>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You say it only deletes the first row. Please be more clear about the end goal.

Comment: your delete statement has "WHERE notif_id = ?", so you delete single row, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Yeah, I probably said it wrong, the problem is that the AJAX only uses the first row like if I select the id 1000 it will still use the id 1 (i'll attach a .gif in a second)  
https://thumb.gyazo.com/thumb/1200/_9f12c592fc900ae5fa7b1247257119fd-gif.gif

Answer (score 0):

As i guess according to your gif -

You are having multiple hidden fields with same name   i.e. notify_id

so whenever you select 'notif_id': $('input[name="notif_id"]').val()
it will obviously select first row.

I think thats the only issue you are facing.

```
just 2 steps - 
1st> in the anchor tag add custom attribute  notifyId="<?=$notif_id?>"
2nd> replace $('input[name="notif_id"]').val() with $(this).attr('notifyId')
```

thats all.

Comment: Yes, could you give any tips on how to fix that?

Comment: sorry, my internet wasnt working. anyway i have updated my answer. it will work because i just did it. let meknow if you face any issue or if you wont understand.